# CiviCRM BuildKit install fails on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: developer, civicrm-buildkit

Running the BuildKit installer script on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS doesn't work - it fails trying to resolve the conflict between the openssl libraries used by Ubuntu's NodeJS/NPM packages and the libssl-dev package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated:

The fix for this has now been merged as https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/pull/427

## Original

**Full solution:** https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/issues/426

*Assuming that we can get this fixed in the BuildKit installer this answer will be updated to reflect such a change.*

1. Install a compatible version of NodeJS/NPM from NodeSource

   - `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -`
2. Download, **don't run**, the *get-buildkit.sh* script.

   - `wget https://civicrm.org/get-buildkit.sh`
3. Using the editor of your choice, edit the downloaded script.

   - `editor get-buildkit.sh`
4. On line **453**:

   - (`PACKAGES="acl git wget unzip zip mysql-server mysql-client php7.2-cli php7.2-imap php7.2-ldap php7.2-curl php7.2-mysql php7.2-intl php7.2-gd php7.2-dev php7.2-bcmath php7.2-mbstring php7.2-soap php7.2-zip php7.2-xml apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.2 nodejs npm php-pear libmcrypt-dev libreadline-dev"`)
     Remove **npm**:
   - (`PACKAGES="acl git wget unzip zip mysql-server mysql-client php7.2-cli php7.2-imap php7.2-ldap php7.2-curl php7.2-mysql php7.2-intl php7.2-gd php7.2-dev php7.2-bcmath php7.2-mbstring php7.2-soap php7.2-zip php7.2-xml apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.2 nodejs php-pear libmcrypt-dev libreadline-dev"`)
5. Make the script executable:

   - `chmod +x get-buildkit.sh`
6. Install BuildKit:
   **Important** The script CANNOT be in the same directory you intend to install BuildKit to!

   - `./get-buildkit.sh --full --dir ~/buildkit`
7. Continue the usual steps from here:

   - https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/#config